# Python - Multiprocessing passing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to do some web scraping and then add it to a unique DataFrame for each Process and then merge all the DataFrames together at the end to avoid Locks.

I tried out the code below and it ran but the DataFrame would only hold the data for a moment but not when the process finish running.

Am I missing something?

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

def add_row_to_db(database):
    database.loc[len(database.index)] = ['Sample', 'Testing']
    print('Added')
    print(f'{database}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    columns_name = ['name', 'power']

    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name)

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_row_to_db, args=(db,))
    process.start()
    process.join()

    print(db)
```

**Output**

```
Added
     name    power
0  Sample  Testing

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, power]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0
```